# VB.NET Short-hand way to define a variable based on a boolean expression (ternary)

Tags: vb.net, ternary

In C# I can do this:

```
string outcome = (success?"succeeded":"failed")
```

But in VB.NET is this syntax the only equivalent operation?:

```
If (success) Then
    outcome = "succeeded"
Else
    outcome = "failed"
End If
```

Comment: Knew there had to be a dupe, nice one @Magnus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
outcome = If(success,"succeeded","failed")
```

Comment: Beat me to it - but just an addition, [C to VB converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) will really help you along your way!